# what is the probability of a subvector lenght being lower than a threshold T?

Tags: probability

Assume that we have a vector $V \in R^d$ which is sampled univormly randomly on a $d$ dimensional unit sphere so $|V| = 1$. $V$ consists of $d$ components such that $V=[v_1, v_2, ..., v_d]$. What is the probability that if I select all possible subvectors $S \in R^n$ from $V$ where $n<d$ at least one of it will have lower length then some threshold $T$.

Since the components of $V$ have chi-squared distribution we can calulcate the probability $p$ of one selection having lower length then T as folows. Let $f(x)$ be a chi-squared probability density function with $n$ degree of freedom.

$$p = \int_{0}^{T} f(x) dx$$

Now we could use the Binomial distribution to calculate the probability that at least one subvector will have length less then $T$
$$\sum_{j=k}^n\binom nj(\sqrt[k]p)^j(1-\sqrt[k]p)^{n-j}.$$

The problem is that I do not think that the expression $(\sqrt[k]p)^j$ make sense cause the probability of one component being less then $T$ is not $\sqrt[k]p$. Can anybody help me out here?

Comment: The "selection" paradigm seems inappropriate here. Since the squared length is the sum of the squares of components, there is a selection that sums to less than $T^2$ if and only if the $d$ components with least magnitude sum to less than $T^2$. That seems like a slightly simpler problem than the selection problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it doesn't seem simplier for me. Of course what you say is true but it is not clear how to calculate probability from that

Comment: If the case $T^2\le\frac12$ is helpful for you, I could post an answer for that. The case $T^2\gt\frac12$ is more involved, since the events for different subsets exceeding the threshold are no longer mutually exclusive; you might then have to do inclusion–exclusion with some not-so-nice integrals.

Comment: It would be interesting indeed quite useful to see the solution for $T^2< \frac{1}{2}$. Thanks

Comment: @joriki can you please post the answer for the case T is less then 0.5? It would be really helpful.

Comment: OK, I'll do that later today.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appriciate it.

Comment: I'm very sorry -- in trying to write it out, I realized that my three-dimensional intuition had led me astray. Even for $T^2\lt\frac12$ the events for different subsets exceeding the threshold are not mutually exclusive, so the solution I had in mind doesn't work.